# Find $\int_0^1g(x)dx$, $\,\,g(x) = \int_0^x\frac{f(t)f^n(t)-(f'(t))^2}{f^2(t)}dt$, $\,\,f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^4}$

Tags: integration

$$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \,f(x) = \frac{1}{x^4+1} $$
$$g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \, g(x) = \int_0^x\frac{f(t)f^n(t)-(f'(t))^2}{f^2(t)}dt$$
$$Find\int_0^1g(x)dx$$
So far I only realized $g(x)$ can be rewritten as: 
$$g(x) = \int_0^x{f^{n-1} -\frac{(f'(t))^2}{f^2(t)}}dt$$
$$g(x) = \frac{f^n(x) - f^n(0)}{n} - \int_0^x{\frac{(f'(t))^2}{f^2(t)}}dx$$
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{n}\bigg(\frac{1}{(1+x^4)^n} + 1\bigg) - \int_0^x{\frac{(f'(t))^2}{f^2(t)}}dx$$
I don't have any clue what to do next, would greatly appreciate any help :).

Comment: How did you get $\int_0^x f^{n-1}(t) dt = \frac{f^n(x) - f^n(0)}{n}$?

Comment: Oh, now I see it, I just treated $f(x)$ as $x$ and applied power rule. That was really stupid..

Comment: By the Fundamental Theorem of calculus we have $g'(x) = \left[(1 + x^{4})^{-n-3} - 16x^{6}(1 + x^{4})^{-6} \right]$.

Integration by parts implies: $I = \int_{0}^{1} g(x) dx = g(0) - \int_{0}^{1} g'(x) x dx$.

Comment: Plugging it into Mathematica outputs a result with hypergeometric functions. Specifically, $$-\frac{3 \left(\pi -2 \mathbb{\space arccoth}(\sqrt{2})\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+_2F_1\left[\frac{1}{4},-1+n,\frac{5}{4},-1\right]-\frac{1}{2}\cdot
_2F_1\left[\frac{1}{2},-1+n,\frac{3}{2},-1\right]+\ln(16)$$

Comment: Oh. It is in a 11th grade textbook, I didn't think it's supposed to be so complicated, especially given that it's not even marked as hard or anything out of the ordinary.